# Putting execution timing code into a function, OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, timing, function-calls

I have this code snippet that I use everywhere in my programs (C++ and OpenCV). It is for timing some operations:

```
double t;

// Some code...

t = (double)getTickCount();

Object1.LotOfComputing();

t = 1000*((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
cout << "Time for LotOfComputing =" << t << " milliseconds."<< endl;
cout << "=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=" << endl;
```

This is how the OpenCV doc recommend to time a function/portion of code and it seems to works for me after using it for some weeks. The times I measure are ranging from about 1ms to 700ms, and I round them to the millisecond.

The problem is that I time a lot of different operations in my program and the code is cluttered by these snippets.

I wonder if it would be wise to put these lines of code into a function, like:

```
double timing(double time){

timing = 1000*((double)getTickCount() - time)/getTickFrequency();
cout << "Time for LotOfComputing =" << timing << " milliseconds."<< endl;
cout << "=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=" << endl;

return timing;

}
```

So I could be able to use this:

```
double t;

// Some code...

t = (double)getTickCount();

Object1.LotOfComputing();

timing(t);
```

I am simply concerned about the execution time of going through function calls... Maybe I am simply worrying for nothing!

Comment: what about logging the timing instead of `cout << endl` all the time? (printing is quite expensive). If you are only worried about the function call, you could replace it with an inline function or a MACRO! But I guess that the printing is more expensive than the function call itself.

Comment: Yes in the future I will log them all instead of printing. Right now it was easier for me to display them on the console, but I'll store them in an array or some variable and display them on the console at the end of all computations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### here's a little profiler magic ;)

basically, it makes static counters per scope (think a pair of {}), which get initialized at module startup, and get read out at module release time. of course this takes time, too, so you don't want this inside some tight loop.

```
// you might want to change the clock
#define get_ticks cv::getTickCount
#define get_freq  cv::getTickFrequency
double dt(int64 t) { return double(t*1000/get_freq())/1000.0; }

struct Profile
{
    string name;
    int64 t; // accumulated time
    int64 c; // function calls

    Profile(const string & name) 
        : name(name)
        , t(0) 
        , c(0)
    {}   

    ~Profile() 
    {
        cerr << format("%-24s %8u ",name.c_str(),c);
        cerr << format("%13.6f ",dt(t/c)); 
        cerr << format("%13.6f ",dt(t));
        cerr << format("%14u",t);
        cerr << endl;
    }

    struct Scope
    {
        Profile & p;
        int64 t;

        Scope(Profile & p) 
            : p(p) 
            , t(get_ticks()) 
        {}

        ~Scope() 
        { 
            int64 t1 = get_ticks();
            if ( t1 > t )
            {
                p.t += t1 - t;
                p.c ++;
            }
         }
    }; 
};

#define PROFILEX(s) static Profile _a_rose(s); Profile::Scope _is_a_rose_is(_a_rose);
#define PROFILE PROFILEX(__FUNCTION__)
```

#### later use it:

```
void foo() {
   PROFILE;
   int k=10;
   while (k) {
       PROFILEX("foo while loop");
       k --;
   }
}
void bar() {
   PROFILE;
}

int main() {
    PROFILE;
    {
        PROFILEX("useless scope");
        bar();
        bar();
    }
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
foo while loop                 10      0.000000      0.000002           3959
foo                             1      0.000007      0.000007          13000
bar                             2      0.000000      0.000000            843
useless scope                   1      0.000004      0.000004           7710
main                            1      0.000017      0.000017          31712
```