# OpenCV calculate time detection features

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, surf

I'm trying to calculate the time that my program takes to detect the keypoints from an image.
If in my c++ program I do it two times (with the same image) there is a huge difference between both. The first time it uses around 600-800 ms and the second time just 100-200 ms.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Here is the code where I get the times:

```
struct timeval t1, t2;

Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create(400);

gettimeofday(&t1, 0x0);

detector->detect( imagen1, keypoints_1 );

gettimeofday(&t2, 0x0);

int milliSeconds = Utils::calculateDiff(t1, t2);
```

Here is the code where I calculate the diff:

```
static int calculateDiff(timeval t1, timeval t2)
{
    return (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec)/1000;
}
```

Here is a sample:

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJdNq.jpg)

Comment: if you create a 2nd image with identical pixel information: `cv::Mat imagen2 = imagen1.clone();` will it need `100-200 ms` or `600-800 ms` to detect? Not sure whether openCV remembers the `integral images` computed by SURF-Detector until the input image is freed or something like that...

Comment: It needs 100-200 ms. My steps: 1. Clone the image 2. Detect features from first image (600-800 ms) 3. Detect features from the copy (100-200 ms)

Comment: what about detecting in a completely different image (same size) after detecting in the first image?

Comment: Same result. First image `600-800 ms` and second image `100-200 ms`. Maybe using `detector->detect(..)` initialize something inside the detector?

Comment: No, I have just created one more detector and it takes just `100-200ms`and the first one `600-800ms`

Comment: maybe the first call needs to "warm up"(initialization etc maybe). try comparing 2nd and 3rd calls.

Comment: 2nd, 3rd and successive calls always `100-200 ms`, no matter if the same detector or new one on each call.

Answer (score 5):

note, that gettimeofday is using wall-time, while problems like this usually require cpu/clock-time.

for profiling, try something (even more portable), like this:

```
int64 t0 = cv::getTickCount();
//
// some lengthy op.
//
int64 t1 = cv::getTickCount();
double secs = (t1-t0)/cv::getTickFrequency();
```

Comment: Same result with identical images. `Test(1): t0-t1 (not in seconds) = 1444919` `Test(2): t0-t1 (not in seconds) = 274456`

Comment: @berak Didn't you have a neat trick for profiling sections of code? I remember as some answer to another question on SO.

Comment: @a-Jays, [maybe this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677324/putting-execution-timing-code-into-a-function-opencv/26678075#26678075) ? but take with a grain of salt, single threaded, and measuring takes time, too..

Comment: @berak yes that one. Quite useful. Maybe combined with `chrono`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use getTickCount(), and getTickFrequency() to count time. however there is a truncation problem when using these functions. After some tries this code worked for me:

```
    long double execTime, prevCount, time;
    execTime = prevCount = time = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
    prevCount = getTickCount() * 1.0000;
    /*do image processing*/
    time += execTime;
    cout << "execTime = " << execTime << "; time = " << time << endl;
    execTime = (getTickCount()*1.0000 - prevCount) / (getTickFrequency() * 1.0000);
    }
```