# How to determine the process time for one image frame (OpenCV , C++, Windows)?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, real-time

Im using Windows 8.1 Pro with Intel Xeon CPU E5 3.7 GHZ, 64 bit. For image processing using OpenCV with Eclipse and C++. Also as a compiler using GCC C compiler. I have done object detection on some images .So for one openCV exe program for object detection would like to know how long it takes to process one image (frame). So would like to know the processing time of my OpenCV code for one image(frame). Which commands in windows can use for that purpose. Should I do first code optimization on level 3 with gcc-03? So is this related with real time processing, like 2fps?

Any help?

Comment: If I understand this question correctly, it has nothing to do with either `opencv` or `image processing`. Plenty of answers on Stack Overflow already, just search for something like "[c++] measure execution time".

Comment: There is no such command to do that, In C++ you can use `std::chrono` to measure time upto nanoseconds precision, And take samples along 10-15 frames, to get approx. mean time.

Comment: see [Cache size estimation on your system?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21509808/2521214) and look for `tbeg(),tend()` usage it uses performance counters from windows ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26678075/2836621